# Python3: HowTo align the formatted output of values from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, string, dictionary, formatting, key

I'm familiar with formatting positional parameters in Python3.
For example:

```
D = {'name': 'Bob', 'status': 'Fully Employed'}
print('"{0:<8}"  "{1:>20}"'.format(D['name'], D['status']))
>> "Bob     "  "      Fully Employed"
```

What I would like to do is to use dictionary keys to identify which value should be displayed with alignment.

Is there an easy way to do this?

I've tried this, but I must be missing something.

```
print( '"{\'name\':<8}  "{\'status\':>20}"'.format( **D ) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'name'"
```

Comment: "I've tried this, but I must be missing something." What you're missing is that this code goes out of its way (with escape sequences) to specify quote marks as part of the names to look up, but the names in question **do not have** such quotes. The code works fine without all the `\'`s. This should be clear from **reading the error message**: it tells you that there is a `KeyError` and that it is trying to look  something up that has quotes in it. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
print('"{0[name]:<8}"  "{0[status]:>20}"'.format(D))
```

Output:

```
"Bob     "  "      Fully Employed"
```